# Request Method not Suported @PathVariable in @RestController in Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a `RestController`, now I wrote a `DELETE` method with `@PathVariable`:

```
@RestController("/msisdns")
public class MsisdnsController {
    @DeleteMapping("/{msisdnToUnReserve}")
    public String unreserveMsisdin(@PathVariable String msisdnToUnReserve) { ... }
}
```

Bult always get the same error... :

[image]

I´ve tried with:

```
@DeleteMapping("/{msisdnToUnReserve}")
public String unreserveMsisdin(@PathVariable("msisdnToUnReserve") String msisdnToUnReserve)
```

or

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{msisdnToUnReserve}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public String unreserveMsisdin(@PathVariable("msisdnToUnReserve") String msisdnToUnReserve)
```

and more but always the same error, I can´t reach the method

Any help?

This is my Zuul.yml, how should be trnslato URI? 
[image]

PD: `/trasnlator` is configured in Zuul with Spring Cloud Netflix.

Comment: Please post the Zuul routes..

Comment: Isn´t Zuul Problem, because it´s works with `@RestController("/msisdns")
    public class MsisdnsController {
        @DeleteMapping
        public String unreserveMsisdin(@RequestParam(name = "msisdn_to_unreserve") String msisdnToUnReserve) { ... }
    }`

Comment: @MiguelCarrasco, might still be a zuul route issue, as the two are technically different routes (even if they can be setup to route to the same location).

Comment: your Zuul is deployed on port number 8089 and the url you are hitting says 8090 . I didnot get how zuul is causing issues here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced a similar problem when I don't specify the `produces` or `consumes`. You can try if that fixes the problem. Choose the proper type (JSON in my example):

`@DeleteMapping(value = "/{msisdnToUnReserve}", produces = org.springframework.http.MediaType#APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`

Answer (score 0):

Use @RequestParam instead of @PathVariable it will work

and Your URL will be like this : localhost:8080/msisdn?id="whatever your id"